# circle pack nodes x, y and r not defined d3.v4

Tags: d3.js

The x and y are not defined in my array when I look at nodes. My code was originally in version 3.

```
 var tree = d3.nest().key(node => node.parent)
 .rollup(function (leaves) {return leaves.length; })
 .entries(data);

 var treeRoot = {
   key: "root",
   value: "100",
   values: tree
 };


  var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([width, height - 50])
  .children(function(d) { return d.values;  })
  .value(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .padding(10);

var nodes = pack.nodes(treeRoot);
```

[initial work no chart yet](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/uo2dedqm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the rollup.  Changed .values to this;

```
 .value(function(d) { return d.value; })
```